# Dropdown Search not working - missing scripts?

Tags: html, search, dropdown, getuikit

I am trying to implement the dropdown search feature from the UiKit, but am having trouble displaying the search bar itself. I have added only the scripts I need this far in my application, maybe I am missing one? Can anyone see what it is I'm missing

[Dropdown Search UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs/search)

Here's my codepen:

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/elszeus/pen/QxrBgz)

```
   <nav class="uk-navbar uk-navbar-container uk-margin">
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">

        <a class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="#">Logo</a>

        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="uk-navbar-right">

        <a class="uk-navbar-toggle" href="#modal-full" uk-search-icon uk-toggle></a>

    </div>
</nav>

<div id="modal-full" class="uk-modal-full uk-modal" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" uk-height-viewport>
        <button class="uk-modal-close-full" type="button" uk-close></button>
        <form class="uk-search uk-search-large">
            <input class="uk-search-input uk-text-center" type="search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these two your `<head>` tags and the search icon appeared + worked:

```
<head>
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.6/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.6/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.6/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

So like this overall:

```
<head>
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.6/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.6/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.6/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</head>

<nav class="uk-navbar uk-navbar-container uk-margin">
    <div class="uk-navbar-left">

        <a class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="#">Logo</a>

        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="uk-navbar-right">

        <a class="uk-navbar-toggle" href="#modal-full" uk-search-icon uk-toggle></a>

    </div>
</nav>

<div id="modal-full" class="uk-modal-full uk-modal" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" uk-height-viewport>
        <button class="uk-modal-close-full" type="button" uk-close></button>
        <form class="uk-search uk-search-large">
            <input class="uk-search-input uk-text-center" type="search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```